# Angular mat-table row highlighting with dialog open

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material2, mat-table

Requirement is to keep row highlighted while dialog is open. Unsure as to what the best implementation would be to keep the row clicked active state when the dialog is opened by clicking on a row
[image]

**Table HTML:**

```
<mat-table class="mat-table-hover mat-table-striped mat-table-active" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
```

**Table SCSS Styling:**

```
// Table highlight rows on active
    &.mat-table-active > mat-row:active {
      background-color: mat-color($accent, lighter);
      cursor: pointer;

      mat-cell {
        color: mat-color($accent, lighter-contrast);
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I've correctly understood, you just have to set an `active` class (with a variable) when the user click on a row. Then, just after have closed the dialog, you reset the variable.

Comment: @Emilien Can you provide a code example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try something like this :

```js
activatedRow = null;
displayedColumns: string[] = [/* Your columns here as strings */];

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

openDialog(row: any) {
  this.activatedRow = row;

  this.dialog.open(YourComponent, {
    width: '250px',
    data: {}
  }).afterclosed().pipe(
    tap(() => this.activatedRow = null)
  );
}
```

```html
<mat-table class="mat-table-hover mat-table-striped mat-table-active" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <!-- Put your columns here -->

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row [class.active]="activatedRow === row" (click)="openDialog(row)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</mat-table>
```

You can visit [Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples) and [Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

Comment: Yeaah cool ! When you can, could you mark my answer as "solve" please ? :)

Comment: @Emillien just did! :) Can you up vote question please?

Comment: @Halfpenny Done !